# A Trio Of Siblings

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> Separated, we are nobodies--
>   unknown, except to a select few.
>   Together, we are a celebrity--
>   the entire world looks up to us.
>
> You may find us in the darkest of times,
>   when we succor those who are lost.
>   But when your world shakes and falls apart,
>   we will likely be hidden from view.
>
> We are not timeless, but we are close enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We are

> Polaris (Aa, Ab, and B).

Separated, we are nobodies--
unknown, except to a select few.

> most people don't know that Polaris is a three-star system

Together, we are a celebrity--
the entire world looks up to us.

> they're in the visible night sky

You may find us in the darkest of times,

> at night

when we succor those who are lost.

> Polaris, being almost collinear with the Earth's axis, indicates the direction due north

But when your world shakes and falls apart,

> 7.5 billion years from now, the sun engulfs the Earth

we will likely be hidden from view.

> 5 million years from now, Polaris goes bang and turns into a neutron star (faint) or a black hole (fainter still)

We are not timeless, but we are close enough.

> lost me here

Comment: Very nice answer. For "unknown, except to a select few", I think it might also be ROT13(crbcyr jvgu gryrfpbcrf), and "We are not timeless, but we are close enough", I think it might be that the lifespan is so large that to humans it feels timeless/permanent.

Comment: Also, perhaps rot13(abg gvzryrff ersref gb gur snpg gung vg vf bayl gur abegu fgne rirel 26,000 lrnef.  Va 13,000 lrnef sebz abj, Irtn jvyy or gur abegu fgne.)